# Update QGIS 2.6 with a bug fix (revision 11c2bae7)

Tags: qgis-2.6

How do I use a `cpp` file to update my QGIS?

I'm talking in this case of the issue in this [link](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/11c2bae74079ab008d7e7fb9233d714409aff008).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are building QGIS from source you will have to grab a nightly build package for your OS, or wait until the release of 2.8

Comment: QGIS 2.6.1 has been released now. So if that fix was backported, it should be included.

Comment: Without any relase notification?

Comment: I'm not sure it has been officially released. Just some of the packages are up early.